# How to insert two buttons in the stack pane?

Tags: javafx

I'm new to the `JavaFx` and I have a very simple question but I tried everything but the second `Button` is not showing pls help me

```
public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

Button button;
Button button1;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    button=new Button();
    button.setText("Click Me");


    button.setOnAction(this);

    Button button1 = new Button();
    button1.setText("Don't click me");

    button1.setOnAction(this);

    StackPane layout=new StackPane();
    layout.getChildren().addAll(button,button1);


    Scene scene = new Scene(layout,1000,250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();



}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource()==button){
        System.out.println("you clicked me;;;;;");
    }
    if (event.getSource()==button1){
        System.out.println("I asked not to click me;;;;");
    }
    }
}
```

I only see one `Button` (only "button1").

Comment: `Button button1 = new Button();` should be just `button1 = new Button();`

Comment: Still only the  button1 is shown. When giving the layout do I need to give 2 separate layout??

Comment: I think both buttons are in the same location and they are overlapping

Comment: Yep, might be the case. Try a [HBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html) instead of a `StackPane`.

Comment: You're using a `StackPane` so it is "stacking" it's children on top of each other. It's behaving exactly as it should be.

Comment: Unless you modify the layout parameters for the children independently, a `StackPane` uses the same alignment for all children. In this case all the children are centered in the `StackPane` and since the topmost one is the largest, you only see one of them. Swapping the order of the children you should see both...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is a modified version of the code you posted. `StackPane` stacks its contained components on top of each other. Hence `button1` appears on top of `button` because `button1` is added last. And because both buttons have the same dimensions, you only see `button1`. In the code below the dimensions of `button` are changed and extra text is added to `button1`, resulting in making it wider than `button` so as to allow you to see that `button1` appears on top of `button` and also enables the user to easily click the mouse either on `button` or `button1`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Buttons2 extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    Button button;
    Button button1;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        button = new Button();
        button.setText("Click Me");
        button.setMinSize(80.0d, 50.0d);
        button.setOnAction(this);

        button1 = new Button();
        button1.setText("Don't you dare click me");
        button1.setOnAction(this);

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(button, button1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 1000, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == button) {
            System.out.println("you clicked me;;;;;");
        }
        if (event.getSource() == button1) {
            System.out.println("I asked not to click me;;;;");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture of the running application.

[image: Buttons2]

Answer (score 2):

The commenters are right correct in that `StackPane` will only show the second button here if its not being used without something to give a vertical and horizontal layout component such as `HBox`. Here is an example to help get the point across.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Separator;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonsApp extends Application {

    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        button1 = new Button("Button1");
        button2 = new Button("Button2");
        button3 = new Button("Button3");
        button4 = new Button("Button4");

        // these two buttons will be stacked one 
        // on top of the other because that is 
        // the purpose of a stackpane which means
        // you will only see the top one (button2)
        var topStackPane = new StackPane(
            button1,
            button2
        );

        // these two buttons are wrapped in a HBox
        // which fills in it's nodes horizontally,
        // side by side from left to right.
        var bottomStackPane = new StackPane(new HBox(
            button3,
            button4
        ));

        topStackPane.setPrefSize(200, 190);
        bottomStackPane.setPrefSize(200, 190);
        var vbox = new VBox(
            topStackPane,
            new Separator(Orientation.HORIZONTAL),
            bottomStackPane
        );

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vbox, 200, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]